# linear algebra computation of area using determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Let $P = (1,0,-1)$ and $Q = (1, 1, 1)$ and $R = (2,2,1)$. Choose $S$ so that $PQRS$
is a parallelogram and compute its area. Choose $T$, $U$, $V$ so that $OPQRSTUV$ is a
tilted box and compute its volume

Answer (score 2):

I cannot comment.

Hyper-area of a hyper-parallelopiped is just the determinant of the a matrix the rows/columns of which are the vectors which give the edges of the shape.

Thus, just calculate your determinants.

But it seems to me that you are missing entries/dimensionality.